# Spring-Boot java.lang.NullPointerException: null at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver...<c:forEach, Validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a basic Spring-Boot application. I use javax.validation in the Controller. It recognizes EL tags as <c:out value="X" />, but when the view has a <c:forEach items="${collection}...It throws :

java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver..

I don't know if it could be a dependency conflict: (Here's my pom, I've marked all servlet dependencies as "provided" but it doesn't work)

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- spring starters -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    

        
<!-- jpa persistence -->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


         

    <!-- bootstrap and dojo -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.34</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- Json -->
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- validation -->
    
    <!-- 
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
 -->
    

<!-- spring framework -->
         <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency-->
        

        <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>

<!-- excel documents -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- math library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    
    
    </dependencies>
```

Or a problem with validation: (Here's part of the controller)

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;

import com.dev.spring.model.tutorial1.EmployeeVO;
import com.dev.spring.service.tutorial1.EmployeeManager;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/the-good-rest/employee-module")
@SessionAttributes("employee")
public class EmployeeController {
   @Autowired
   EmployeeManager manager;
   String basePath = "tutorial1/";
   private Validator validator;

   public EmployeeController()
   {
       ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
       validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getAllEmployees(Model model)
   {
       model.addAttribute("employees", manager.getAllEmployees());
       return basePath + "employeesListDisplay";
   }
```

This is the jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%--@elvariable id="employees" type="com.dev.spring.model.EmployeeVO"--%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Hello World</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h2>All Employees in System</h2>
 
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td>${employee.id}</td>
                <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
                <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to me you nowhere instantiate a collection called employees. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I forgot to mention that "manager.getAllEmployees" returns an non empty Collection

Comment: I added <%--@elvariable id="employees"... at last option, it didn't work with or without

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to make the application work. Is to configure spring-boot as spring-mvc application.

I've changed in POM:(Added)

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         
<!--The rest of dependencies passed from provided to compile-->
```

Changed in SpringApplication some TomcatConfigurationBean (remove)

Deployed in Tomcat 8.1 and all <c:Tags works fine, no changes needed